# Problem understanding the concept of random sample

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I'm reading a book on statistics and the definition given of a random sample doesn't make much sense to me.

Here's the idea that I have of a random sample: in a given population, any sample of size $n$ has an equal probability of being chosen. Let $x'_1$,..., $x'_n$ be the values of the first,..., and last element of the first sample of size $n$; let $x''_1$,..., $x''_n$ be the values of the first,..., and last element of the second sample of size $n$, and so on and so forth. Let $X_1$ be the random variable associated with values $x'_1$, $x''_1$, etc.; $X_2$ be the random variable associated with the values $x'_2$, $x''_2$, etc.

If $X_1$,..., $X_m$ are independent variables and each $X_i$ has the same probability distribution then ($X_1$,..., $X_m$) are a random sample.

Am I wrong or right?

Comment: You seem to have said $x'_1,\ldots,x'_n$ is a random sample and $x''_1,\ldots,x''_n$ is another random sample and so on.  Why complicate things after that?

Comment: I guess because I don't understand the definition. But do you think I'm correct?

Comment: A common definition of a random sample from a distribution is that the $X_i$'s are independent and each has the population distribution. // Why not post the definition that is giving you trouble and ask for clarification, instead of trying to invent your own.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but I had some troubles recently. I didn't try to invent anything. I just tried to rephrase the definition so I could understand it.